# Suppose a random variable X has mean 0 and moment generating function as follows, find values of a and b

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

$M_x(t)=a(1+e^{-2t}+e^{-t} +e^t+be^{2t}), -\infty<t<\infty$

Do I take the first derivative of this function? How do I solve for two variables given only one equation?

And as a followup question, how do I obtain the probability mass function of X from the moment generating function?

Edit: Taking Andre's hint, $M(0)=a(4+b)=1$ and $M'(0)=a(-2+2b)=0$. Solve these two equations and obtain $a=\frac{1}{5}, b=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**  We have $M_X(0)=1$  and $M_X'(0)=0$.

For your second problem, we can read off $\Pr(X=0)$, $\Pr(X=-2)$, $\Pr(X=-1)$, $\Pr(X=1)$ and $\Pr(X=2)$
from  the mgf.

Comment: So the pmf will be a function of discrete values?

Comment: In this case, yes. For a proof, note that a finite number of discrete values gives an mgf of this type, and then appral to thr uniquness theorem.